# Get profile picture to show up in OpenID in Disqus

Tags: openid

I am using my openID to comment on blogs that use Disqus. However when I comment on articles Disqus just uses their generic avatar instead of my photo. My openID provider is myopenid.com. I haven't been able to find any resources on how to do this, and cookies are set so Disqus recognizes me when I go to sites now.

How can I get my profile to show up when I log in to my openID in Disqus?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Disqus doesn't allow for the use of OpenID avatars as the profile image.

Also, it looks like the services that Disqus is using to import avatar images aren't OpenID providers. Source: http://openid.net/get-an-openid/

I tried to find some options around (like ifttt.com) to see if there was a way to automatically update your gravatar/Facebook/Twitter image when you update your open id image. I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gravatar](https://en.gravatar.com/). But it only works on Wordpress